# ng-model using two dynamic value

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use check list where ng-model will bind the selected data based on two dynamic value.
My code is:

```
<div ng-repeat="individualFieldInfo in formInatiatingData">
       <div ng-repeat="individualListItem in individualFieldInfo.list"
           <input type="checkbox" ng- model=
   "userGivenData[individualFieldInfo.fieldName][individualListItem.value]">   
              {{individualListItem}}
            </div>
</div>
```

Here,

```
 userGivenData[individualFieldInfo.fieldName][individualListItem.value]"
```

is not workng.
My  JSON is:

```
 $scope.userGivenData={

 }
$scope.formInatiatingData =  [
   {
        type:"checkList",
        fieldName:"Fruit",
        list : [
            {
                id:1,
                value:"mango"
            },
            {
                id:2,
                value:"Banana"
            },
            {
                id:3,
                value:"Jackfruit"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

For single dynamic binding userGivenData[individualFieldInfo.fieldName] is working. But, for two dynamicvalues, its not working.
I am searching for a way where if a user check a checkbox, it will be binded in userGivenData.fieldName.value

Comment: what value you need to bind while check ?

Answer (score 2):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope){
  $scope.someComplex = {
    someInnerObj: {
      thisIsAProperty: 'withSomeValue'
    }
  };
  
  $scope.thing1 = 'someInnerObj';
  $scope.thing2 = 'thisIsAProperty';

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <pre>{{someComplex|json}}</pre>
  <pre>{{someComplex[thing1][thing2]}}</pre>
  <input type="text" ng-model="someComplex[thing1][thing2]"/>
</div>
```

In a test case this does work... can you output some more of the data objects values you show there like I did in the sample here using the json filter and pre tags?